# Open source Twitter clone (in Ruby/Python)

Tags: python, ruby, twitter

Is there any production ready open source twitter clones written in Ruby or Python ?

I am more interested in feature rich implementations, not just bare bones twitter like messages (e.g.: APIs, FBconnect, Notifications, etc)

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure this is a viable project? Twitter is a beast to compete with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two relevant projects:

- http://github.com/insoshi/insoshi
- http://github.com/dmitryame/echowaves/wiki

Sadly both appear discontinued

Answer (score 3):

I know of twissandra which is an open source clone. Of course I doubt it meets your need of feature rich implementations.

Comment: though arguably, simplicity is why twitter are so successful

Comment: I prefer code that is battle tested or at least used. A sample "demo" project is a nice start but will require lots of work to bring to prod level.

Answer (score 2):

http://github.com/rnielsen/twetter

From their readme:

> Twetter is an implementation of the twitter.com API, designed for use in situations where internet access is not available but a large number of people have twitter clients and want to tell each other what they are doing, for example a RailsCamp, where it was first developed.
>
>
>
> The current goal is to have it work with as many third party twitter clients as possible.  It has currently been tested with Twitterific, TwitterFox, and Spaz on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

The following open source alternative to twitter : http://identi.ca/ is written using the the software http://status.net/ . It looks like it is written in PHP too.

Also there is http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/ which is a microblogging platform for google app engine. This should serve as an example for python implementation.

Also look at http://www.typepad.com/go/motion/

Comment: motion works on top of the typepad APIs, so from what I understand can't be really used as a local private service.