# Question about Django's feed framework

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to setup a feed for my app, but I'm a little confused.

I'm aiming for something like the one on bitbucket/github's dashboard.

So my user creates lists, and the lists will have items. Users can also follow other users and their lists.

I want my feed to show:

- The activities for the user on his lists
- The activities of other (followed) users on their lists

How is this set up?

Answer (score 1):

The [Django Syndication Framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/) focuses on providing RSS (or other syndication format) feeds. Feeds are usually just an XML document that provide the fields required for the format involved. The framework does not include any kind of feed reader, which is what the front-end to githubs dashboard is.

I believe you're on your own for the frontend, but you can look at a number of RSS readers source for inspiration.

Also, re-reading what you wrote again, it sounds like you're after a twitter-like following system. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758440/open-source-twitter-clone-in-ruby-python) that explores OS twitter clones. Try to take a look at the model structure, and UI, for `following` users. This should be a fairly good jumpstart. Correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: Thanks. I already have a following system using [django-follow](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-follow) and [django-relationships](https://github.com/coleifer/django-relationships). What I'm confused about is how I should set up the Feed class to include all the models from the different apps into one feed. I thought about creating a separate app called "activity" which has a single model which holds all the activity of a user/list by using events and then create a Feed for that.